# Firestore Import - no error, but no changes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I'm attempting to use the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import to a) do periodic backups of data from my production instance, and b) copy data between production/staging/dev instances.

For what it's worth, each instance is in a separate Firebase project (myapp-dev, myapp-staging and myapp-production), all are on the Blaze plan and each has a corresponding bucket in Cloud Platform (gs://myapp-backup-dev, ...-staging, ...-production).

I've successfully completed all the "Before you begin" steps.  I've exported data from one instance/project  (staging) into it's bucket, and it **seems** that I can also import it back into that project successfully (no error message, operationState: SUCCESSFUL), but any records changed since the export don't 'restore' back to their original values.

And for what it's worth, I've also successfully copied the exported data from that bucket into another project's bucket (staging to dev), and get the same result when I am importing it into the second project (dev).

Am I doing something wrong here?  Missing something?

Comment: Does the completed import operation show the correct value for `workCompleted`?

Comment: I don't see workCompleted when I run `operations describe [op name]`...  Here's what I get from that command:

`done: true
metadata:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.admin.v1beta1.ImportDocumentsMetadata
  collectionIds:
  - "'testStuff'"
  endTime: '2018-10-15T21:46:29.256743Z'
  inputUriPrefix: gs://myapp-backup-dev/2018-10-15T21:38:18_36964
  operationState: SUCCESSFUL
  startTime: '2018-10-15T21:45:56.910282Z'
name: projects/myapp-dev/databases/(default)/operations/[truncated]
response:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Empty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the name of your collection `testStuff` or `'testStuff'`? If it's `testStuff`, it seems like your export command was slightly off. You'll need to export the data again. You should get a `workCompleted` number this time around.

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://myapp-backup-dev --collection-ids='testStuff'

gcloud beta firestore import gs://myapp-backup-dev/2018-10-15T21:38:18_36964 --collection-ids='testStuff'
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much.  The docs on that page are a bit misleading, as they provide the collection ids in quotes.  

`--collection-ids='[COLLECTION_ID_1]','[COLLECTION_ID_2]'`

I've submitted that as documentation feedback.

Comment: @JuanLara Sadly this did not fix the problem for me :/ I exported the whole database which seems like it worked fine but exporting a single collection just results in a lot of output-x files which are empty and only one output files which contains a little bit of data but importing does not create any documents. Any idea what the source of error could be?

Comment: If you look at `gcloud beta firestore operations list`, did the operations complete successfully and does the work completed look correct? If not, please open another question with more details and example commands.

Comment: @Niklas Vest I have the same problem. Have you got dashes in any of your collection names?

Comment: @nsandersen I am sorry to tell you but I don't remember what solved the problem. If I recall correctly one of the problems was that I assumed that a collection mentioned in the command would be "deep-backup-ed", but if you want to export nested collections, you have to include those explicitly. I don't remember the syntax for that, though.

Comment: Thank you, this turned out to solve my problem. I tried adding the name of my nested collection after the main one, ie. `--collection-ids=main_coll,nested_coll`. Interestingly this is only necessary sometimes, it was not necessary for test cases I made. I suspect that is related to access rules, which I did not replicate for my test cases, but I cannot verify that at this time. The dashes were a coincidence in this case.